# British citizen joining US startup as co-founder, tax considerations for stock agreements

Tags: united-states, taxes, united-kingdom, start-up

I am joining a startup as a co-founder which is incorporated in the US. I am a British citizen (not a US citizen) and will work from the UK, whereas my co-founders will be working from the US.

As part of joining the company, I will be signing a stock agreement and joining the board of directors as a chief officer. As far as I'm aware, these documents are not part of an employment contract, which I will complete at a later stage when taking a salary (I won't be paid in the short term whilst we ramp-up the company through 'sweat equity').

Does anyone know if there are any implications to signing these contracts from a UK tax perspective?

I would expect joining as a chief officer of a US company and agreeing to the stock agreements doesn't trigger any initial tax implications from the UK side, but I will be completing an 83(b) election from a US perspective just in case. I'm just not sure if there are any specific things I may need to take into consideration before signing, or whether I can action on these over the course of the tax year.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How's a 83(b) election relevant to you if you're not a US taxpayer? Also, check how it works with the UK labor laws, a foreign corporation having a local employee and such...